# How to disable the conhost.exe window, while running your project's .exe file qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

I've been looking for a while now for a solution, but nothing really works for me. I mean I tried using

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release):DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
```

but it does not do what I want - when I run my .exe file that was deployed in release version I just want to have my program's window. Is there a way to disable that debug console completely?

Comment: Did you try  `CONFIG -= app_bundle` ?

Comment: @tunglt it does not work either :/